# Hibernate count issue using 2 fields

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql

In a SparePart table the uniqueness of the rows is given from a combination of materialName and materialNumber , what i want to do is get the total number of Spare Parts avalaible now.

I have tried using count(distinct ...) but it only works for one field not two.

The SQL query(using hibernate query language) with an inner query would look like this :

```
select count(*) from (
     select distinct materialName, materialNo from SparePart
) as col
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a subquery+group by and then filter for the first ID that represents the particular group, finally count all those that match the filter:

```
SELECT COUNT(sp2) FROM SparePart sp2 WHERE EXISTS
  (SELECT sp.materialName, sp.materialNo
          FROM SparePart sp
          GROUP BY sp.materialName, sp.materialNo
          HAVING MIN(sp.id)=sp2.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use hibernate dialect for this task. To do this, create your own dialect, that extends dialect of DB what used ([list of all dialects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html)), and then register new function. For example, I use MySQL 5 with InnoDB engine:

```
public final class MyDialect extends MySQL5InnoDBDialect {
    public MyDialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("pairCountDistinct", new SQLFunctionTemplate(LongType.INSTANCE, "count(distinct ?1, ?2)"));
    }
}
```

After then add new property in persistence.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="com.example.dialect.MyDialect" />
```

And now you can use this function:

```
// some init actions
final CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<Long> criteria = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
final Root<SparePart> root = criteria.from(SparePart.class);
criteria.select(builder.function("pairCountDistinct", Long.class, root.get(SparePart_.materialName), root.get(SparePart_.materialNo)));
final long result = entityManager.createQuery(criteria).getSingleResult();
// some close actions
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with Criteria API.

```
ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();        
projectionList.add(Projections.property("materialName"));
projectionList.add(Projections.property("materialNo"));

Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(SparePart.class); 
criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(projectionList);  
criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());

Long results = criteria.uniqueResult();
```

Also, it may need some modifications as I haven't tried it, mapped according to your query.